# How to display PSObject in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm building a PowerShell host by C#, and I want to display the result after invoking PowerShell. Now I use the following method:

```
public static string GetLogQueriedString(
    PSMemberInfoCollection<PSPropertyInfo> PSPropertyCollection)
{
    string line = string.Empty;
    foreach (var item in PSPropertyCollection)
    {
        if (!line.Equals(string.Empty)) line += ",";
        line += item.Name + " : " + item.Value;
    }

    return line;
}
```

It works if the PSObject has many properties that I need, but in this situation, if the PSObject is a string, the result is not what I want. It will display "Length: 40", rather than the string itself.

And another question: if I execute several PowerShell commands, why will it display all the results, including the previous result. For example, I execute "ls; get-process", and it will display the result of "ls" and the result of "get-process".

Comment: This `"ls; get-process"` makes it look like you're telling PowerShell to execute two commands in the same pipeline.  It will do so and return both results.  It does the same from the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think we need to see more of your code.  The typical approach to display returned PSObjects is:

```
using (var ps = PowerShell.Create()) {
    while (true) {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter an expression:");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)) break;

        ps.AddScript(input);
        Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
        foreach (var result in results) {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't need to access properties on the returned objects and all you're interested in is the formatted text try changing this line:

```
ps.AddScript(input + " | Out-String");
```

If you want to do custom formatting based on object type, you will need to test for the type and format as you see fit:

```
foreach (var result in results) {
    var baseObj = result.BaseObject;
    if (baseObj is System.Diagnostics.Process)
    {
        var p = (System.Diagnostics.Process) baseObj;
        Console.WriteLine("Handles:{0}, NPM:{1}, PM:{2}, etc", p.HandleCount, p.NonpagedSystemMemorySize, p.PagedMemorySize);
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to display the result as the following format: key:value, but if the psobject is a string, it will display: "Length:100",what i want is the string itsself.

Comment: for example, if i typein "get-process", i want is to display "Handles:83, NPM:23, PM:21, WS:1234, VM: 280, CPU: 12, ID:12, Process-Name: conhost" like this, line by line. if the result is a string or a integer, i want to display it. for example, if i typein "$list.count", it will display a number.

Comment: how to deal with it if the psobject is another type?

Comment: You test with `is` for each type you want to handle formatting.  For strings, datetime, bool, numbers, etc you could just fall through to the final else clause which asks the object for its string representation using ToString() implicitly.

Comment: for a pshost, i don't know exactly what type of the psobject is, is there any method that can get the type of the psobject?

Comment: You can use `psobject.BaseObject.GetType()`.

Answer (score 0):

More of your code is needed, but just a clarification of the previous answer.... It may be helpful to think of PSObject LIKE an array, in that each value is a key-value pair. Because of this, if you try to explicitly cast like `ToString`, you'll get the object type, much like if you try to cast an array to a string you'll get a memory reference.

An easy solution is to use a `foreach`. For your code:

```
foreach(var r in results) {
  string toConsole = r.ToString()
}

Console.WriteLine(toConsole);
```